# Find the sample size necessary to determine the true proportion within 5% at the 10% level of significance

Tags: statistics

I do not understand what this question is asking and this question also states that no preliminary estimated proportion is given. Also find the preliminary estimated proportion of 70%.

Comment: What parts don't you understand?  Do you understand the terms *sample size, true proportion,* and *level of significance*?  Let us know what you *do* understand so that we don't have to start at the absolute beginning.

Comment: I do not understand any of what it is asking for.